# Does entropy principle apply to human behaviour?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, entropy

Imagine that I invite 100 people to a room and once they enter, I close the room and in case (A), let them sit randomly and in case (b) ask them to take up seats alphabetically as per their name by promising a monetary reward. Now, the energy spent in case (b) will likely (but not necessarily) be higher. But what happens to entropy? Is it guaranteed to increase? Or will the room temperature increase because of decreased disorder in (b)? Can this system be considered closed?

Can humans come together and deliberately cooperate to seeming violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Case (b) depends on whether you intend to keep your promise of monetary reward. If you don't, disorder may increase.

Answer (score 2):

In either case entropy associated with how you arrange people in the room will be negligible compared to the increase in entropy due to the biochemical processes involved with keeping the people alive. Consequently the second law has no real effect on human behaviour.